# IntelliJ Properties Files "Transparent native-to-ascii conversion" how to exclude paths or files

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

The ***"Transparent native-to-ascii conversion"*** in IntelliJ is very good. But I only need it for i18n. I also have native Characters in my other configuration Properties files. I don't want them to be converted. Is there a way to ***exclude*** paths or files for this ***"Transparent native-to-ascii conversion"*** feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to exclude files for this feature. [Related request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189919), a [new request is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).

Comment: I am not a paid user and just started trying IntelliJ. I don't know if I can put a request there.

Comment: You don't need to be a paid user to submit bug reports or feature requests in YouTrack.